# i want to pass a string from one input box to another in different page

Tags: php

i want to pass a string from an input box that after submition automatically goes to different page and the string gets copied in the input box in that page .the Language I am using is php.

Comment: have a look at the $_POST and $_GET variables...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second page, you need to read the incoming value from the input box and include it in the output (which includes the second input box). Do not forget to pass the value of the variable through `htmlspecialchars`, since you are outputting it as part of your HTML.

So the code for the second page would look something like this:

```
$incoming = $_REQUEST['name_of_input_box_1'];
echo '<input type="text" name="name_of_input_box_2" value="'
     .htmlspecialchars($incoming).'" />';
```